# Excel VBA function with Recordset (Performance issue)

Tags: vba, excel, recordset

I have a database in SQL Server that I'm using to feed some financial reports in Excel. I'm using Recordsets through a custom Excel Function that uses arguments from Cells to build the SQL queries. Here is how the code looks:

```
 Public Function Test(arg1 As String, arg2 As String, arg3 As Integer, arg4 As Integer, arg5 As String) As Variant
    Dim oConnection As ADODB.Connection
    Set oConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim oRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Set oRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "SELECT SUM(BALANCE) as Total FROM Accounting WHERE ARGUMENT1 = " & Chr$(39) & arg1 & Chr$(39) & " AND ARGUMENT2 = " & Chr$(39) & arg2 & Chr$(39) & " AND ARGUMENT3 = " & Chr$(39) & arg3 & Chr$(39) & " AND ARGUMENT4 = " & arg4 & "  AND ARGUMENT5 = " & arg5 & ""

    oConnection.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
                         "Data Source=(IP of database);" & _
                         "Initial Catalog=(catalog of database);" & _
                         "Trusted_connection=yes;"

    oRecordset.Open Source:=strSQL, ActiveConnection:=oConnection, CursorType:=adOpenForwardOnly, LockType:=adLockReadOnly, Options:=adCmdText


    Test = oRecordset!Total

        oRecordset.Close
        Set oRecordset = Nothing


End Function
```

So, this code works very well but I'm having a performance issue. I have to fill dozens of cells, and each cell uses different arguments coming from different cells. So I have reports that take over 1 minute to load fully.

I'm using adOpenForwardOnly, but are there any other fine tunings I can do to the code to speed up things?

Thank you very much

Comment: Can't you get all the lines at once, using a `GROUP BY` query ?

Comment: I don't quite understand your setup. Is just running 1 iteration of `Test` taking over a minute? You can add a timer variable to check between your code what is taking long to calculate. Might be some latency from querying your SQL. Can you do an ad hoc query directly from your db to see if the performance issue might be from that?

Comment: I agree with iDevlop, you should pull a whole data set over to your workbook in one shot, preferably into a Pivot table where you can group by your arguments and then refer to the pivot table in your formula. Recordsets in functions are notoriously slow. Also don't forget to close your connection and set it to Nothing!

Comment: The problem with taking the whole data in one shot to one worksheet is that the excel file gets extremely big (even if I import everything to a Pivotable). I'm talking about >40M files :( I need to work with ACTUAL information, ACTUAL -1 and Budget. And I need access to all accounts and cost centers from our General Ledger. Doing recordset allows me to keep our Balance Sheet and P&L files around 1M, which is great. Btw, you're right about closing the connection, Thanks

Comment: nbayly, 1 single interation takes like 2 seconds to retrieve the data to the excel cell (which is much slower that running the same query in SQL Server). As the reports have dozens of Cells, sometimes it take 1 to 2 minutes to fully update the reports. What I'm searching for is possible solution that can save me 30 to 50%

Answer (score 0):

If your data is not particularly time-sensitive then you can "memoize" your UDF by having it cache previously-queried results using a dictionary object.

Untested:

```
Public Function Test(arg1 As String, arg2 As String, arg3 As Integer, _
                            arg4 As Integer, arg5 As String) As Variant
    
    Static dict As Object   'maintained between calls
    Dim k As String, rv
    Dim oConnection As ADODB.Connection
    Dim oRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String

    'create the dictionary if not already created
    If dict Is Nothing Then
        Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    End If
    
    'create a unique "key" from the arguments
    k = Join(Array(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5), Chr(0))
    
    'need to run this query?
    If Not dict.exists(k) Then
    
        Set oConnection = New ADODB.Connection
        Set oRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
        
        strSQL = "SELECT SUM(BALANCE) as Total FROM Accounting WHERE ARGUMENT1 = '" & _
                 arg1 & "' AND ARGUMENT2 = '" & arg2 & _
                 "' AND ARGUMENT3 = '" & arg3 & "' AND ARGUMENT4 = " & arg4 & _
                 "  AND ARGUMENT5 = " & arg5 & ""
    
        oConnection.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
                             "Data Source=(IP of database);" & _
                             "Initial Catalog=(catalog of database);" & _
                             "Trusted_connection=yes;"
    
        oRecordset.Open Source:=strSQL, ActiveConnection:=oConnection, _
                        CursorType:=adOpenForwardOnly, LockType:=adLockReadOnly, _
                        Options:=adCmdText
    
    
        rv = oRecordset!Total
    
        dict.Add k, rv
        
        oRecordset.Close
        Set oRecordset = Nothing
    
    Else
        'already ran the SQL - just return the result
        rv = dict(k)
    End If

    Test = rv
    
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test that solution! This would only save me time if the query was previously executed right?

Comment: Yes- it's more about preventing queries from bein run repeatedly when excel recalculated the sheet.  As the other commenters suggested you might find it quicker to pull back all the data and query it client-side.  Really depends on how much data you have.