# In Access VBA functions, is it possible to have objects and variables be persistent between calls..?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I've written a custom function in Access 2007 that's used in queries to process a certain complicated field. Since the function runs many thousands of times during a query, I've carefully written it to be as fast as possible. But it's still a bit slow, and to make it faster I'd like to modify it so the variables and objects persist between calls, and perhaps even wrap it in a custom class.

But how can there be such persistence without wrapping up the queries so they run from within a VBA code module..? What are the boundaries of the VBA environment during a query..? In the situation where a function is called from SQL, it starts, does its thing, and then stops, once for each field that it's called for, hundreds or thousands, even millions of times. There's no form module where I can define module-level variables or objects. [that I know of]

If VBA functions are called from a query running in the standard Access user interface window, how can such functions have persistent variables, objects and classes across calls..?

Comment: In VBA you can define Global or Static variables which persist as long as the VB project does (absent some event which resets all variables).  Question is a little abstract though - it would help to actually show your function.  There are methods which can be used to speed things up, but which might be most appropriate for your case really would depend on the specifics.  E.g. one way to do it is to use a Dictionary to cache function results: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048266/excel-vba-function-with-recordset-performance-issue/34059374#34059374

Comment: Ok, I see the static dictionary. But it's in Excel, not Access. The basis of my question revolves around the idea that a function is called once for a field in every record the query processes. In the case of a query being run from the main Access window, when does the VBA module load and unload? Is it when the query starts and ends, or as each *record* is processed? Of course if a query is run via DAO from a parent code module, everything stays loaded. But if run from the main window, then what? I may have to set up a test project for this, with a variety of objects to see what happens.

Comment: That was just an example.  The answers to your questions are tied up in the code you haven't posted.