# Can I speed up this VBA function that queries an (AWS) mysql db?

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I've written a function (see below) that queries an external MySQL database that's set up on AWS and returns a single value. It works fine - just like I wanted it to, really - except that it's fairly slow. If you're just using the function in a spreadsheet once, it's fine, but if you want to pull, say, 10 different numbers from your database into your spreadsheet, there's an annoying pause of several seconds (15?) while they all update. 
It's not the end of the world, but it seems like it could/should be faster.

I wondered if the problem was that I was opening a new connection to the db each time I ran the function, so I tried to split the process up into a Sub that connects to the db, and a function that just submits the queries (see further below). I thought I'd run the "Connect" Sub once when I first opened the spreadsheet, and then use the querying function as needed, but that didn't work at all. I just got a "#VALUE" in any cell that included the function.

I realize that this is a pretty open-ended question and I apologize, but I'm stumped, and I thought someone on stackoverflow might have some good suggestions. It just seems like this should be faster than it is. 
It probably goes without saying, but: I'm new to VBA and find it pretty wonky and confusing.

Original function:

```vb
Public Function Quer(Param1 As String, Param2 As String, Param3 As String)

    Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs1 As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim connstring As String

    Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection

    connstring = "connection string"

    Conn.Open connstring

    Dim querystring1 As String

    querystring1 = "Select " & Param1 & " FROM table WHERE Param2 = " & Param2 & " AND Param3 = " & Param3

    Set rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs1.Open querystring1, Conn

    Record = rs1.GetRows

    Quer = Record(0, 0)


End Function
```

Like I said, the above function seemed to work fine, just slow.

My "second attempt" was the following, which tried to split up the main database connection and the individual queries. This was a complete failure, as far as I could tell, but maybe there's some easy fix that I'm missing. Or does it matter? Would this approach be faster even if it worked?

```vb
Sub Connect()

    Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim connstring As String

    Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection

    connstring = "connection string"

    Conn.Open connstring
End Sub

Public Function Quer(Param1 As String, Param2 As String, Param3 As String)

    Dim querystring1 As String
    Dim rs1 As ADODB.Recordset

    querystring1 = "Select " & Param1 & " FROM table WHERE Param2 = " & Param2 & " AND Param3 = " & Param3

    Set rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs1.Open querystring1, Conn

    Record = rs1.GetRows

    Quer = Record(0, 0)

End Function
```

Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: The problem with Connect() is that the connection is only local to that function, it would need to be a *Module Level Variable* instead.  You should add some timing code to see if its the connection or query that takes the most time.  The obvious way to speed up the query is to build a single SQL statement that queries for multiple items at once - i.e making only one trip to the DB - but this depends of your use case of the function.

Comment: Concatenating values to SQL statements opens you up to SQL Injection vulnerabilities/bugs, ADO supports Parameterized Queries which fix this.

Comment: Also, make sure you set the recordset to readonly.

Comment: If you're running this as a UDF, then you could/should use something like a dictionany to cache the result for a given set of inputs, so instead of re-running the query each time the worksheet calculates, you can return a cached result (which clearly will be much faster).  How long you cache the result depends on your data and how volatile it is.   Eg:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048266/excel-vba-function-with-recordset-performance-issue/34059374#34059374

Comment: @Alex K. Yes! That worked! Just moved the "Dim Conn as ADODB.Connection" before "Sub Connect()" and my sheet now updates correctly and wonderfully fast. Thank you, thank you. Geez. Wow. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Alex K.'s comment above, I changed the code as follows:

```
Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection

Sub Connect()

    Dim connstring As String

    Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection

    connstring = "connection string"

    Conn.Open connstring
End Sub

Public Function Quer(Param1 As String, Param2 As String, Param3 As String)

    Dim querystring1 As String
    Dim rs1 As ADODB.Recordset

    querystring1 = "Select " & Param1 & " FROM table WHERE Param2 = " & Param2 & " AND Param3 = " & Param3

    Set rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs1.Open querystring1, Conn

    Record = rs1.GetRows

    Quer = Record(0, 0)

End Function
```

Conn is now set as a module level variable, so it works in both the Sub Connect() and the Quer function. With this change, the Quer function works and does, indeed, update much faster. 
This change does not address the security/vulnerability issues with my code, but it solves my initial problem and helps me considerably with what I'm trying to do. 
Thanks to everyone who commented for your help.